# In CartoDB I want to import geo-referenced points based on where I took photos

Tags: carto, photos, photo2shape

In CartoDB I want to import geo-referenced points based on where I took photos and then, I'd like to see the photos / photo URL when I hover over the points.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this, you'd need that the file you're importing includes the coordinates (latitude and longitude) for your photos.

Then, you just need to configure the on hover infowindows and add a  tag in their custom HTML infowindow.

Your table (CSV format, for example) could be something like:

```
latitude, longitude, photo_url, description, title
39.36, -4.04, http://mywebsite.com/my-photo.jpg, Awesome!, Madrid
```

And assuming your photo_url column is called "photo_url", your infowindow on hover custom HTML could be:

```
<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content-wrapper">
<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content">
<h4>name</h4>
<p>{{name}}</p>
<p>{{description}}</p>
<img src="{{photo_url}}" style="width:90%;" /></p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Matthiaus Clausen,

If you import the data and you have two columns called **lon** and **lat**, it will be geo-referenced automatically

Example.csv:

```
lon;lat;photo;
4;3;url_1..;
5;6;url_2..;
1;2;url_3..;
```

Then, you could customize your infowindow (see [tutorial](http://blog.cartodb.com/full-editing-of-infowindow-html/)) (and hovers) with the photos.